# webpack is unable to find entry point

Tags: webpack

I'm beginning to experiment with webpack.

I'm following a tutorial from Sitepoint published here: https://www.sitepoint.com/webpack-beginner-guide/

I'm using the following package.json

```
{
  "name": "project-stub",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./src/js/main.js",
  "scripts": {
      "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
       "dev": "webpack --mode development",
      "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.41.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10"
  }
}
```

When I run build or dev, the error message indicates that 'main.js' can't be found.
This remains true no matter if I put main.js in the project root, in the src directory or in the js directory. It remains true no matter how I edit the "main" element of this config.

A typical error look like this:

```
 project-stub@0.1.0 build /home/bob/play/learning-react-2
> webpack --mode production


Insufficient number of arguments or no entry found.
Alternatively, run 'webpack(-cli) --help' for usage info.

Hash: 43455f82066e07e4ac75
Version: webpack 4.41.5
Time: 40ms
Built at: 2019-12-28 16:19:32

ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in '/home/bob/play/learning-react-2'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! project-stub@0.1.0 build: `webpack --mode production`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the project-stub@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/bob/.npm/_logs/2019-12-28T03_19_32_117Z-debug.log
```

How do I tell webpack where my source files are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell Webpack where your source files by creating a `webpack.config.js` in your root, and adding this code to it.

```js
module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/js"
};
```

You can read more on configuration [here](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/configuration).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I am trying to follow the react tutorial at https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/

I have created the following webpack.config.js file

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/main/js/app.js',
    devtool: 'sourcemaps',
    cache: true,
    mode: 'development',
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: './src/main/resources/static/built/bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: path.join(__dirname, '.'),
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
                    }
                }]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

My entry file (./src/main/js/app.js) has the following code

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hi</h1>,
  document.getElementById('app'),
);
```

When i run mvn generate-resources the ./src/main/resources/static/built/bundle.js gets created.

My index.html file that is the first file to get loaded in browser is as follows --

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>ReactJS + Spring Data REST</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/main.css" />
</head>
<body>

    <div id="react"></div>

    <script src="built/bundle.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see it is calling the built/bundle.js when i look in the developer tools in chrome i see that the budle.js is getting called but i see a blank page in the browser. Not the message "Hi" rendered by app.js produced above. So this may throw some insight for someone else who might answer on this thread.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).